# Mysql query throws error when passed to db as text but works as a stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to run the following query in my app:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs jo
INNER JOIN units un ON jo.unitid = un.unitid
INNER JOIN complex co ON un.complexid = co.complexid
WHERE co.complexid = xcomplexid AND jo.status = xstatus
```

This should get a list of all maintenance jobs stored in the jobs table for the specified complex (I always use `x<column name>` for my parameter names and they always work fine) that have the specified status set.

Now, if I run this through as a text command (using System.Data.CommandType.Text), I get the following error (it works if I run the query clean on the db with filled in values):

> Unknown column 'xcomplexid' in where clause

If I copy this select into a stored procedure and use `System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure` instead, it'll work.

While this makes it obvious what I should do, I really don't understand why .NET or MySQL are literally forcing me into using SPs... Is this something I'm doing wrong?

My full code follows (please be aware that about half of this is as yet untested):

```
private enum FilterType
{
    None = 0,
    Complex = 1,
    DateRange = 2,
    Subcontractor = 3,
    MultipleSubcontractors = 4
}

private FilterType filter;

private void loadReport()
{
    string cmd = String.Empty;

    List<MySqlParameter> args = new List<MySqlParameter>();

    // xstatus will be used in all Report queries
    args.Add(new MySqlParameter("xstatus", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
    args[args.Count - 1].Value = ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Value;

    // filter has been set previously in execution by actions performed by the user
    switch (filter)
    {
        case FilterType.Complex:
            cmd = "select * from jobs jo inner join units un on jo.unitid = un.unitid inner join complex co on un.complexid = co.complexid where co.complexid = xcomplexid and jo.status = xstatus";

            args.Add(new MySqlParameter("xcomplexid", MySqlDbType.Int32));
            args[args.Count - 1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlComplex.SelectedItem.Value);
            break;
        // other cases will appear here
    }

    // Database(string CommandText, System.Data.CommandType CommandType, List<MySqlParameter Parameters)
    using (Database db = new Database(cmd, System.Data.CommandType.Text, args))
    {
        Session["reportData"] = db.GetDataTable();
        // db.GetDataTable simply populates a data table
        // with the data returned by the query through the
        // use of a DataAdapter

        gvItems.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["reportData"];
        gvItems.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running as text command, you have to add a parameter to the command object with name `'@xcomplexid'` to make it work.(Like you do for stored procedure.)

```
cmd = "select * from jobs jo inner join units un on jo.unitid = un.unitid inner join complex co on un.complexid = co.complexid where co.complexid = @xcomplexid and jo.status = xstatus";

            args.Add(new MySqlParameter("@xcomplexid", MySqlDbType.Int32));
            args[args.Count - 1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlComplex.SelectedItem.Value);
            break;
```

Comment: The 2 lines under the sql statement do exactly that

Comment: Okay, can you explain what the difference is and/or why one works over the other?

Comment: .net follows specific notations to identify the variables in the sql queries. to represent a variable inside a text query /stored procedure would be @<variablename>. In your case when you say <variablename>, .net could not differentiate column name in the query and variables.

Comment: So .net can't tell that x<variablename> is a parameter which isn't an issue when passing the value in this way to the SPs?

Comment: Yes, please look at the following link for more detailed info,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
cmd = "select * from jobs jo inner join units un on jo.unitid = un.unitid inner join complex co on un.complexid = co.complexid where co.complexid = @xcomplexid and jo.status = @xstatus";

args.Add(new MySqlParameter("@xcomplexid", MySqlDbType.Int32));
```